# Is the client an actor in a local system?

Tags: uml, use-case

Suppose we are building a local system in a company. Client can fill out a form in a paper while the employee submits this form using the computer.
Is the client an actor in this system?

It will be helpful If there is any good reference to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, "no" -- actors carry out use cases in the system.  A use case is a set of scenarios linked by a common user goal.

That said, I would consider the client in the flow as the form may be incomplete, incorrect, etc.  Logically, there should be correction, resubmission, amendment processes that involve new input from the client.

With respect to references, Martin Fowler's **UML Distilled** is reasonably readable and useful.  Many other texts seem to get doctrinaire about orthodoxy and over-design.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I agree to the answer of @Stand__Sure.

However, you do not tell enough context to really decide. What happens to the paper? It seems logical that filling out the paper is "somehow" connected to the system under consideration. So at least I'd document the actor even if he just produces a superfluous paper. That would at least show some stakeholders that "something is wrong in the state of Denmark".

Furthermore I'd recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases.